# Multiple foreign keys in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have 2 models which is associated like

```
class Taxonomy < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :user_taxonomies , :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :users, :through => :user_taxonomies
  has_many :companies, :through => :user_taxonomies
end

class UserTaxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :taxonomy
end
```

What is want: while create taxonomies, it should give list of `users` in `select (multiple: true)`. It should create entry in `UserTaxonomy` table with company_id (it will be the same for all users).

How can I achieve it with `nested_form`?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `nested_form`.

Comment: @Emu how? Can you add code snippets? I had try using nested form but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Try using multiple option in select like this:

```
<%= f.select :users, 
             User.all.collect {|u| [ u.email, u.id ] }, {}, 
             { :multiple => true, :size => 10 }
%>
```

Take note of the empty hash `{}` which is required for it to work properly. `size` will be the height of the select field or you can use css for styling.

The result should look like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10">
    <option value="4">user3@domain</option>
    <option value="3">user2@domain</option>
    <option value="2">user1@domain</option>
    <option value="1">user0@domain</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want to create entries in join table user_taxonomies.  not users and companies